# Moving a custom variable from MFCApplication32Doc to MFCApplication32View

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a variable I have stored in 'CDocument' which I need to transfer to the 'CView' class. However, I do not know how to do this and how to do it only when the open file dialog closes. So, if at all possible, is there a way to transfer this variable and detect when the file dialog closes?

Comment: How do you mean "transfer a variable"? copy over the contents?  NOTE: if the variable in the document class is public or has a "Get" function in your document class, the view can always access the value of the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to keep data in CDocument, and access it from CView:

```
//CYourDocument header

protected:    
    m_sDataString;
public:
    CString GetData() const {return m_sDataString;}
```

and from your CView:

```
CYourView class
CString sData = GetDocument()->GetData();
```

If you want to know when user open or save a document, you can override [CDocument::OnOpenDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebc8c52a.aspx) and [CDocument::OnCloseDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9700x58.aspx).